# How to convert a D2009 .groupproj file to a D2006 .bdsgroup file?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2006

I'm trying to convert a .groupproj project group file (from Delphi 2009), to use with Turbo Delphi Explorer, i.e., convert to .bdsgroup. The file structures are similar (xml). There are a easy way to do that? How?

Comment: Surely a group project is just a collection of projects. You can just build it up in the IDE in a few seconds.

Comment: "Derek WildStar"? Anime reference?

Comment: @Fabricio Araujo - Sim... era o desenho que eu mais gostava em minha infância: Patrulha Estelar

Comment: @David Heffernan - My intention is just don't do that :)

Comment: @WildStar - in english, boy. Or the other people will not get the "Star Blazers"(the name on US) reference.

Comment: @Ðerek It would have been quicker to do it in the IDE than to even write this question. I must be missing something.

Comment: @David Heffernan - yes, unfortunately

Comment: @Fabricio Araujo - OK, I'll do that next time, but Starblazers is very good ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I guess @David Heffernan was right. I'm loosing time trying to convert a new .grouproj to a old .bdsgroup, so, I'm answering my own question: There are no easy way to convert a .groupproj to .bdsgroup, it's more easy to compare the packages "visually" opened into two IDEs the old and the new and so, create a new .groupproj from the old one.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to make a mapping between those XML formats, then write a transformation to transform from the Delphi 2009 format to the Delphi 2006 format.

A good way for writing transformations between various XML formats is using [XSL-Transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) ([XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt)).

XSLT is a very powerfull language, for instance, [Internet Explorer uses an XML Stylesheet](http://www.google.com/search?q=res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl) (res://msxml.dll/defaultss.xsl) to transform XML files into HTML and display them as a tree structure.

Comment: This approach might take longer than the IDE-based approached suggested by David in his comment above...

Comment: All we need now is a Linq based solution and we got all the overkill bases covered

Comment: If the formats are sufficiently similar, then the XSLT approach is very straightforward. Now we need to find a volunteer that does it once :>

Comment: @Jeroen Pluimers - :) Who will do that?

Comment: Andreas Rejbrand - Yes, unfortunately :(

Comment: @Ðerek mail me two equivalent config files and I'll see what I can do.